# Got a SQLCODE = -991

Tags: db2, cobol, jcl, tso, sqlcode

After the sub of the exec JCL, i've got the following error :

SQLCODE = -991
Error = ALL ATTACH WAS UNABLE TO ESTABLISH AN IMPLICIT CONNECT OR OPEN TO DB2

This error is triggered when i call a module that allows to query a table.

PS : i have the necessary privileges for the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [IBM's page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/dsnc1k17/3.2.476?ACTION=MATCHES&REQUEST=991&TYPE=FUZZY&SHELF=dsnshka6.bks&DT=20100614130926&CASE=&searchTopic=TOPIC&searchText=TEXT&searchIndex=INDEX&rank=RANK&ScrollTOP=FIRSTHIT#FIRSTHIT):
-991   CALL ATTACH WAS UNABLE TO ESTABLISH AN IMPLICIT CONNECT OR OPEN TO DB2. RC1= rc1 RC2= rc2

And some general links for SQL return code information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DB2_SQL_return_codes
- http://theamericanprogrammer.com/programming/sqlcodes.shtml
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=64&uid=swg27011656 - use the searches here to find lots of things
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you [included](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=bcsr-include-statement) [DSNALI](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=program-invoking-call-attachment-facility) in your [program bind](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=components-binder) (aka link) step, and that you're running on the correct LPAR.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are not running on the same LPAR as DB2 and you don't have sharing enabled.